# Converting between svg and browser coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I know this question has been answered in other posts, but the responses don't seem to resolve the issue that I have. I am trying to get an svg point from a browser point and am getting lost in all the different names for coordinates systems and their nuances.

#### Result A

```
var point = svgElement.createSVGPoint();
point.x = 0;
point.y = 0;
var result = point.matrixTransform(svgElement.getScreenCTM());
```

The code above results in one value:
`SVGPoint {x: 520.4003295898438, y: 198.69253540039062})`

I thought the term **screen coordinates** meant that the coordinates are in the space or your entire screen (not just the browser), but this point is invariant to where the browser is in the screen (if I move the browser around, this does not change).

#### Result B

`window.screenX` and `window.screenY` do seem to refer to the browser's position within the entire screen of your computer and do change as you move the browser around.

#### Result C

I tried `svg.getBoundingClientRect()`, which gives me the value:

```
{
    top: 43,
    right: 1144.09375,
    bottom: 1080,
    left: 504,
    width: 640.09375…
 }
```

Notice that the left and top value do not match the svg point coordinates from **result A**.

So at this point, I am a bit confused. What is the *getScreenCTM()* returning? It doesn't seem to agree with *screen coordinates* (the coordinates of your entire computer screen) or *client coordinates* (the global coordinates of the browser).

I would deeply appreciate any help in figuring this out, if anyone knows what *getScreenCTM()* is doing.

Thank you!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh535760(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: "screen" in getScreenCTM means "viewport on screen surface". That matrix defines transformation from local object coordinate system to viewport coordinate system,